# Changing UIImage using an IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c

Good morning,

I am trying to create a button, that, when pressed, will change the background to a different image.

For example; we have;

background1.png
background2.png
background3.png
background4.png
background5.png
background6.png
background7.png
background8.png
background9.png

I want the app to start, and use background1.png as the default.

However, I would like to set a UIButton, to change the background when pressed, that will just cycle through the backgrounds from 2-9.

Is that possible to do at all? At present the Background image is set in the IB using 'background1.png' so I am guessing I would need to remove that, and set it to appear in the viewdidLoad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, set the image view containing the background image to an IBOutlet.

Then, in the IBAction pointed to by your UIButton, each time that action is called you can cycle through the various image files and set the image contained in the UIImageView.

e.g.:

```
- (IBAction) changeBackgroundImageAction: (id) sender
{
    // someIndex can be an ivar or something else... 
    NSString * imageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"background%d.png", someIndex];
    backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: imageFileName];
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest not changing the image in the action method, but dispatching a block to do it to the main thread. You may want to experiment to see what looks best.

Comment: @DavidH - I understand why one would want to use a block to do network or CPU intensive stuff asynchronously, but why would you suggest using a block for something super simple like this?

Comment: Because you don't want to change the image while the button is highlighting and unhighlighting the original image. By dispatching a block, it gets deferred until the next run of the main runloop. In some cases changing appearances in the delegate method really makes a UI element look bad, but the transition always looks good when deferred.

Comment: Michael, your method is good thank you :)